# Wrong value while getting the triple duplicate

Tags: java

I have developed a java code that takes a text file as input and selects the duplicate words and gives output by creating a new text file containing the duplicate words, now I need it to select triple duplicated words, but i cannot get it correctly. below is my java code-

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CheckDuplicate {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FileReader file1=new FileReader("/home/goutam/workspace/DuplicateWord/clean_2014.txt");

    BufferedReader reader1=new BufferedReader(file1);

    File f=new File("Reduplication.txt");

    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f);

    String line=reader1.readLine();

    while(line!=null){

        String[] arr=line.split(" ");

        if(arr.length>1){

            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

                if(i<arr.length-1){

                    int cmp=arr[i].compareTo(arr[i+1]);

                    if(cmp==0){

                        fw.write(arr[i].toString());

                        fw.write("\n");

                    }

                }

            }
        }

        line=reader1.readLine();

    }
    reader1.close();

    file1.close();
}
```

}

Comment: What result you are getting?

Comment: postthe output and tell what is wrong about the output, that way its easy to  debug

Comment: When you say "triple duplicated", you mean appearing three times in a row? Your program only has a check for words that appear two times in a row.

Comment: As a side note: you can eliminate the condition `if(i<arr.length-1)` if you change the end condition of your `for` loop to `arr.length-1`.

Comment: Yes, i mean appearing 3 times in a row@panonski

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work because you're only considering adjacent elements.

Instead of having nested loops, you can achieve what you want easily using [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that String as a value and an integer that indicates the count as the value.

- When you first encounter a string, you insert it with a value of 1
- When you have a string that's already in the map, you simply increment its value

Then you can iterate on the values and pick the keys with value > what you want.

I highly recommend you using the debugger, it helps you better understanding the flow of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the items to appear 3 times in a row, I modified my code to achieve your goal:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FileReader file1 = new FileReader("/home/goutam/workspace/DuplicateWord/clean_2014.txt");

    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(file1);

    File f = new File("Reduplication.txt");

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);

    String line = reader1.readLine();

    while (line != null) {

        String[] arr = line.split(" ");

        if (arr.length > 1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

                if (i < arr.length - 2) {   // change from length-1 to length-2

                    int cmp = arr[i].compareTo(arr[i + 1]);

                    if (cmp == 0) {
                        if (arr[i + 1].equals(arr[i + 2])) { // keep comparing the next 2 items

                            System.out.println(arr[i].toString() + "\n");

                            fw.write(arr[i].toString());
                            fw.write("\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        line = reader1.readLine();

    }
    reader1.close();

    file1.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, note: I did not compile nor test it but at least it should provide you some directions.

```
public void findRepeatingWords( int atLeastNRepetitions ) {
    try ( BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("/home/goutam/workspace/DuplicateWord/clean_2014.txt") ) ) {
        // There are libraries that can do this, but yeah... doing it old style here
        // Note that usage of AtomicInteger is just a convenience so that we can reduce some lines of codes, not used for atomic operations
        Map<String, AtomicInteger> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>() {
            @Override
            public AtomicInteger get( Object key ) {
                AtomicInteger cnt = super.get( key );
                if ( cnt == null ) {
                    cnt = new AtomicInteger( 0 );
                    super.put( key, cnt );
                }
                return cnt;
            }
        };

        String line = reader1.readLine();
        while( line!=null ){
            // Note we use \\W here that means non-word character (e.g. spaces, tabs, punctuation,...)
            String[] arr = line.split( "\\W" );
            for ( String word : arr ) {
                m.get( word ).incrementAndGet();
            }
            line = reader1.readLine();
        }
    }
}    

private void writeRepeatedWords( int atLeastNRepetitions, Map<String, AtomicInteger> m ) {
    File f = new File( "Reduplication.txt" );
    try ( PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( f ) ) ) {
        for ( Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger> entry : m.entrySet() ) {
            if ( entry.getValue().get() >= atLeastNRepetitions ) {
                pw.println( entry.getKey() );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing you are searching for, I have performed it using LinkedHashMap, It's a dynamic code, you select not only double, triple but also go for n number of time.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class A3 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(
            "src/Source/A3_data"));

    PrintWriter duplicatewriter = new PrintWriter(
            "src/Source/A3_out_double", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter tripleduplicatewriter = new PrintWriter(
            "src/Source/A3_out_tripple", "UTF-8");

    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String line = reader1.readLine();
    while (line != null) {

        String[] words = line.split(" ");
        int count = 0;

        while (count < words.length) {
            String key = words[count];
            Integer value = map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1;

            map.put(key, value);
            count++;
        }
        line = reader1.readLine();
    }

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() == 2)
            duplicatewriter.println(entry.getKey());

        if (entry.getValue() == 3)
            tripleduplicatewriter.println(entry.getKey());

    }
    duplicatewriter.close();
    tripleduplicatewriter.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This this code print if count is greater than 3 you can use any number

```
public static void getStringTripple(String a){      
        String s[]=a.split(" ");
        List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(s);
        Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(asList);
        for(String ss: mySet){
            if(Collections.frequency(asList,ss)>=3)
                System.out.println(ss + " " +Collections.frequency(asList,ss));
        }       
    }
```